# Google Script to copy and list the last row from all spreadsheets in a folder

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I am looking to create a google script that allows me to list the following in a separate spreadsheet (in columns):

- column A, obtain the name of all spreadsheets in a given folder
- column B, obtain the url of said spreadsheets
- Column C, obtain the last cell of the first sheet in each spreadsheet
- Column D, create an importrange formula with the information above

**Key information:** All spreadsheets only have one sheet. There are no empty rows on these sheets and they all have the same amount of columns.

I have accomplished Column A and B. However, I have no idea how to get the last of each spreadsheet. I assume that column D will be easier to write as the only variable in the formula for importrange is the lastBelow is what I have:

```
function gatheredInfo(){
  var result = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
  var folder = DriveApp.getFolderById('FOLDERID');
  var list = [];
  list.push(['Name','URL']);
  var files = folder.getFiles();
  while (files.hasNext()){
    file = files.next();
    var row = []
    row.push(file.getName(),file.getUrl())
    list.push(row);
  }
   result.getRange(1,1,list.length,list[0].length).setValues(list);
}
```

Any help/guidance is genuinely appreciated. I have been stuck on this for a while.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The get to the "last cell" you need to tell the script to open each spreadsheet while you are in the "while" loop and and you can use the lastrow and lastcolumn to do so.

*Edit Note** Depending what you actually mean by 'last cell and how your data is structured you might need to tweak the look up for the cell and notation.. but this will get you to the correct part of your code and concept*

This is the section that I added to do this to your code...

```
//Checks if the file type is a Google Sheet
    if(DriveApp.getFileById(fileID).getMimeType() == MimeType.GOOGLE_SHEETS){
      //Gets the current spreadsheet and first sheet to open to look for the last column and row
    var CurrSheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById(fileID).getSheets()[0];
      
      //find last row, column, and put that into A1 notation
    var lastrow = CurrSheet.getLastRow();
    var lastColumn= CurrSheet.getLastColumn();
      //if you don't need A1 notation then this will spit out the row number and the column number.. this next line is what gives you A1 most easily.
    var lastcell = CurrSheet.getRange(lastrow,lastColumn).getA1Notation();
    
    var row = []
    row.push(file.getName(),file.getUrl(),lastcell);
    list.push(row);
    }
```

First I added a check to make sure the file in the folder is a Google Sheet (that's the mime type).  This will help you prevent errors if something that is not a google sheet happens to make it's way to that folder.

Then we open the sheet by the fileID that you already established.  I defaulted this to the first sheet in each spreadsheet (that's this part   .getSheets()[0]).  You said you only have one sheet but, just incase.

Then use that to get the last row and last column, and I put that together in a fake range to get it into A1 notation more quickly for you.  Then that just gets pushed into the last column of your already established array.

Here is the whole code.  I tested with a folder I have with mixed file types and it works correctly.

```
function gatheredInfo(){
  var result = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
  var folder = DriveApp.getFolderById('FOLDERID');
  var list = [];
  list.push(['Name','URL','Cell']);
  var files = folder.getFiles();
  while (files.hasNext()){
    file = files.next();
    
    var fileID = file.getId();
    
    //Checks if the file type is a Google Sheet
    if(DriveApp.getFileById(fileID).getMimeType() == MimeType.GOOGLE_SHEETS){
      //Gets the current spreadsheet and first sheet to open to look for the last column and row
    var CurrSheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById(fileID).getSheets()[0];
      
      //find last row, column, and put that into A1 notation
    var lastrow = CurrSheet.getLastRow();
    var lastColumn= CurrSheet.getLastColumn();
      //if you don't need A1 notation then this will spit out the row number and the column number.. this next line is what gives you A1 most easily.
    var lastcell = CurrSheet.getRange(lastrow,lastColumn).getA1Notation();
    
    var row = []
    row.push(file.getName(),file.getUrl(),lastcell);
    list.push(row);
    }
  }
   result.getRange(1,1,list.length,list[0].length).setValues(list);
}
```

As for making the importrange formula, you could do this in the sheet itself with a formula or in the app script by just pushing a text string that combines all of these variables.

However, I did not include this because I don't have all of the information to put together a successful importrange() formula.  You need the URL, the sheet name, and the range and I do not know what your sheet names are or if they are the same.  If you do need that too, then you could add this right below the CurrSheet variable (var SheetName=CurrSheet.getSheetName();).  Which would give you the name of the first sheet in your spreadsheet that you are pulling the cell info from. You could just parse that into your app script to either output the suggested importrange() formula or push it as it's own column to use a formula in the sheet.

If you need more detail with that let me know. I just didn't want to assume too much about your situation.

Comment: Thank you so much! Your modifications have steered me in the right direction. I applied the changes you noted with the exception of the last cell. I realized that the last cell was not being picked up because it was empty. However, the last row in the first column was not and this number is exactly what I need. As you mentioned before, I think I may end up pushing a text string in order to list the formula. Once again, tysm; I had been stuck for days as I had seen other examples of looping through files but I couldn't piece it together.